# Выделение цветов в C#

Tags: c#

При вводе слова в richTextBox2 оно должно искаться в richTextBox1 и окрашиваться цветом при нажатии на button3_Click. Но слово не закрашивается.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string line;

    for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            // Чтение одной строки
            line = richTextBox1.Lines[i];

            int idx = line.IndexOf(richTextBox2.Text);

            if (idx > -1)
            {
                richTextBox1.Select(idx, richTextBox2.Text.Length);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: а где в коде вы красите текст цветом?

Comment: Я новичок и еще незнаю как это сделать ((

Comment: что то сами гуглили? Что то пытались?

Comment: string a = "12345678";
// Эта функция красит текст полностью
a.ForeColor = Color.Red;

Comment: Нашел пока только это

Comment: ^^ это даже не скомпилируется, у строки нет цвета.

Comment: платформа какая? WinForms? WPF? WebForms? Xamarin? UWP?

Comment: WinForms использую

Comment: [Color different parts of a RichTextBox string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1926264/312041)

Comment: richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green

Comment: Спасибо ZIBER MINSK. Все сработало!!